# Capital outflow from the US

Tags: national-accounts

There's a lot being discussed about investors from the US diverting capital to emerging markets in early 2022. Is there any official recording of capital outflow in the US, so we could tell how much USD has left the country in a given time period?

Comment: There is data for example at https://www.bea.gov/data/intl-trade-investment/international-transactions but the latest is for 2021 Q3 and while it measures capital inflows and outflows - look at tables 6,7,8 of https://www.bea.gov/sites/default/files/2021-12/trans321.pdf -  this is much more than "investors from the US diverting capital to emerging markets"

Comment: There is surely much more than that, I just wanted to clarify what I was interested in. Thank you for your answer.